# how can i do a jquery auto refresh every x amount of seconds, but only if form field is not being edited?

Tags: jquery

I want to expand on this code so that is pauses the timer and doesn't execute if any form field on the page has cursor inside of it (is focused), then when focus is removed (is blured), continue the timer so it reloads the php file every 10 seconds.  Is that possible?

```
<div id="data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshdata();
});
function refreshdata(){
    $('#data').load('data.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshdata, 10000);
    });
}
</script>
```

Tried this.  This doesn't work...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshdata();
    $('#data').load('data.php');
});

function refreshdata(){
    $(document).focusout(function(){
        $('#data').load('data.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshdata, 10000);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the next refresh to occur 10 seconds after you move the focus out of an input field, you can respond to the `.focus()` and `.blur()` events to stop or restart your timer.

```
var timer;

function startRefreshTimer() {
    stopRefreshTimer();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timer = null;
        // start next timer before .load so if focus event 
        // comes in during the .load, the timer will get cancelled
        startRefreshTimer();
        $('#data').load('data.php');
    }, 10 * 1000);
}

function stopRefreshTimer() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    startRefreshTimer();
    $('#data').load('data.php');
});

// handle blur and focus events to suspect refresh while editing
$("input").focus(function() {
    stopRefreshTimer();
}).blur(function() {
    startRefreshTimer();
});
```

---

This is perhaps a bit cleaner with a `setInterval` instead of a `clearInterval`:

```
var timer;

function startRefreshTimer() {
    if (!timer) {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $('#data').load('data.php');
        }, 10 * 1000);
    }
}

function stopRefreshTimer() {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    startRefreshTimer();
    $('#data').load('data.php');
});

// handle blur and focus events to suspect refresh while editing
$("input").focus(function() {
    stopRefreshTimer();
}).blur(function() {
    startRefreshTimer();
});
```

---

If your dynamically loaded content has `input` fields in it that you are trying to monitor, then you need to do something different.  One option is to use delegated event handling.

```
var timer;

function startRefreshTimer() {
    if (!timer) {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $('#data').load('data.php');
        }, 10 * 1000);
    }
}

function stopRefreshTimer() {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    startRefreshTimer();
    $('#data').load('data.php');
});

// handle blur and focus events to suspect refresh while editing
// use delegated event handling for dynamically loaded content
$(document.body).on("focus", "input", function() {
    stopRefreshTimer();
}).on("blur", "input", function() {
    startRefreshTimer();
});
```

Note: In this third version, you would ideally replace the `document.body` with a selector of a parent of all your input fields that is not dynamically loaded, but is closer to your content than the body element.

Comment: tried your different versions before and after you were editing them.  each time when the timer has reached it's count-down, it forces the input to lose focus.

Comment: @leoarce - then your code must be doing something that changes the focus because this code never changes the focus.

Comment: same with the 2nd version.  timer runs down and input loses focus and timer just continues to refresh every 10 seconds.

Comment: Does your dynamically loaded content have `input` fields in it (an important fact you didn't disclose)?  If so, then you have to either rehook up event handlers on them or switch to delegated event handling.

Comment: yes, the page being loaded into the div is the page with the form fields.  what's the work-around?

Comment: @leoarce - I added a third version to my answer that uses delegated event handling that will work with dynamically loaded content.

Comment: it did stop timer when input had focus, but on blur this error came up and the timer did not resume: ReferenceError: startRefreshtimer is not defined

Comment: @leoarce - that's just an inadvertent typo.  Did you look at the error and the code to see what might be wrong yourself?  It's not that I don't want to help you here, but that's an elementary error and I'd like to help you to solve simple problems like this yourself.  Hint, I fixed the code in my answer already.

Comment: thanks a bunch! :D works.  i should have noticed that typo before asking.  sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60045/discussion-between-leoarce-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Get the active element using `document.activeElement` when you change focus on any element. When you get the active element, check if it's a form field and clear the interval. If it's not a form field, set the interval again :)

Comment: This doesn't provide any way to restart the interval once it's been stopped.

Comment: @jfriend00 actually, it does. I just didn't provide the code itself. I did say to "set the interval again"

Comment: No, you said "check if it's a form field and clear the interval.  If it's not a form field, set the interval again.".  So, if it is a form field, you stop the interval and never provide a mechanism to start it again.

Comment: @jfriend00 if it's a form field, the interval should stop. when you lose focus of the form field, the interval will be set again.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearTimeout when a form field receives focus, and setTimeout on blur.

```
var timeoutCount;
var initCount = function() {
    timeoutCount = setTimeout(function() {
        // refresh
    }, 10000);
}
initCount();

$('form :input').focus(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutCount);
});

$('form :input').blur(function() {
    initCount();
});
```

Comment: This could do a refresh right after focus left the field.  It won't wait 10 seconds after focus left the field.